# Manipulate $f(a,b,c,d) = \frac{a}{b} - \frac{c}{d}$ so that the resulting expression can be seen as $g(a-c, b-d)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Is there a clever way to manipulate the difference $$f(a,b,c,d) = \frac{a}{b} - \frac{c}{d}$$
in such a way that the resulting expression can be seen as $g(a-c, b-d)$, i.e. a function of just  the difference $a-c$ (or $c-a$) and $b-d$ (or $d-b$)?

Answer (score 5):

No it’s not possible because it isn’t actually a function of those inputs. Take the two examples
$$a=3, b = 1, c = d= 3, ~~~ \text{and} ~~~ a= 3, b=1, c=d=4$$
Then for both examples, $a-b=2$ and $c-d=0$, but $a/b - c/d$ Is different.